# Convert number to "boolean bit array" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a number 5. How to get a "boolean bit array" like the array below?

`array = [false, false, true, false, true]; // 00101`

(Need reserve the first two false)

Comment: @zlumer no, it is different. that is also my question.

Comment: @zlumer No, it's not a duplicate. Please read the question before flagging, otherwise you will possibly be banned from doing so in the future.

Comment: I updated my answer in the other thread.

Comment: How is it different? The question you ask is an inversion of the question -- but the accepted answer contains the answer to the original question and the answer to the inverse asked here.

Comment: @Martin "[edited 10 mins ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35296733/revisions)" - Originally, that answer did not contain the inverse. Also, the "inverse" portion of that answer is off-topic (although indeed helpful) for that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
("0000" + Math.abs(number).toString(2)).slice(-5).split("").map(Number).map(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in typescript.

```
async maskIntToBool(argument: number, arrayLen?: number) {
        const binarystring = argument.toString(2);
        const binaryCharArray = binarystring.split('');
        if (arrayLen) {
            //padd if required
            while (binaryCharArray.length < arrayLen) {
                binaryCharArray.unshift('0');
            }
        }
        const binaryintegerArray = binaryCharArray.map(Number);
        const booleanArray = binaryintegerArray.map(Boolean);
        return booleanArray;
    }
```